# Wrong output of SimpleDateFormat with milliseconds ( SSSSSSS )

Tags: java, sql-server, datetime, format, simpledateformat

I am parsing MS SQL date with java.text.SimpleDateFormat but it is giving me wrong output. According to the documentation of [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), it should parse correctly or may be I am missing something.

```
System.out.println( new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS" ).parse( "2016-02-29 13:02:50.2870000 +00:00" ) );
Incorrect Output with milliseconds format
>> Mon Feb 29 13:50:40 PKT 2016
```

However if I try without SSSSS it gives me expected result.

```
System.out.println( new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ).parse( "2016-02-29 13:02:50.2870000 +00:00" ) );
Correct Output without milliseconds format
>> Mon Feb 29 13:02:50 PKT 2016
```

Why there is difference of 47 minutes and 50 seconds ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've specified that there are 2870000 milliseconds - which is 47 minutes and 50 seconds.

It's important to note that in `SimpleDateFormat`, `S` is a *milliseconds* specifier, not a "fraction of second" specifier. Basically, if you're specifying more than `SSS`, it's going to go badly.

Now in terms of your issue - if you're getting a date from a database, you shouldn't have a *string* value to parse at all - you should have a `java.sql.Date` or `java.sql.Timestamp`. If you're storing date/time data as text, that's a problem you should address separately.

If you *have* to do this parsing, I'd just chop off the last four digits and parse it with `.SSS` at the end instead. It's not like a `java.util.Date` can maintain sub-millisecond precision anyway.

Alternatively, you could use `java.time` or Joda Time as *much* better date/time APIs - and `java.time` supports nanosecond precision. Within [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), the `S` format specifier *does* mean "fraction-of-second".

Comment: Thanks for pointing out : 2870000 milliseconds = 47 minutes and 50 seconds.